# Why are my javascript functions are stacking?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a messaging system and I have recently implemented a file uploader, and my javascript functions aren't working, if I press the input file button then press cancel, the next time I upload a file it does it 3 times. It's as if since I don't upload anything, they just sit there and then the function stack. Here is my input :

```
<input type="file" id="file" onclick="bro()"name="file" value="FILE UPLOAD" style="opacity: 0;z-index: 100000; bottom: 17.5px; position: fixed; right: 10px;">
```

And here is my javascript function

```
function bro() {

    document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = this.files[0];

  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", file);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
  var fullurl = '../backend/sendvideosandimages.php?id=' + group_id;
    xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
      };
  };
  xhr.send(fd);
}, true);
};
```

The problem is, I can't just put the function because I use an ajax request thing to display the input. To explain more since I am making a messaging system I have a sidebar with group id and group name. I use this function :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxLoad(page, id, id2){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('mainpage');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var queryString = "?id=" + id + "&id2=" + id2;
    //alert(page + queryString);
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", page + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}

//-->
</script>
```

The problem  is that if I put the event change listener by itself, then it bugs because when the home page loads, the mainpage does not have a input yet. And if I put a script in the mainpage it doesn't execute

Comment: You have an on-click handler which itself adds another on-change handler. So each time there is a click on the `input` another event listener is added.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: Get rid of the onclick and the function so the addEventListener gets called on page load

Comment: Where's that cancel button you are talking about? And where's the handler to cancel the request after having clicked that missing cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

It is stacking because of multiple `eventListeners` . there only should be 1 `eventListeners` .

Firstly, take  `document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener` out of `bro()` function.

Whenever you calling function. It is adding new `change` listeners without removing before one.

thus seems like `bro` function has no use;

This will work :

```js
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = this.files[0];

  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", file);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
  var fullurl = '../backend/sendvideosandimages.php?id=' + group_id;
    xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
      };
  };
  xhr.send(fd);
}, true);

//OR 

function bro() {
document.querySelector('#file').removeEventListener('change',(e)=>{console.log('removed listener')})
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = this.files[0];

  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", file);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
  var fullurl = '../backend/sendvideosandimages.php?id=' + group_id;
    xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
      };
  };
  xhr.send(fd);
}, true);
}
```

Comment: It never console logs, (the problem is still there)

Comment: where is console in code? Is there value for `this.files[0]`

Answer (score -2):

Remove the change event handler and then try.

You need to remove this:
`document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change'`

Right now you have two events on file upload.

1. Change event.
2. Click event.

When you click it adds a change event hence multiple uploads.

Here either you can remove change event code or remove the event listener every time you click.

Try these fixes and see if it works.